# How to consume the front-end for API Authentication in laravel passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have created an API Authentication system in `Laravel` using passport package. now I want to use it in  web site and i have save the `access_token` in browser `cookie` and add the `access_token` in request header using middleware for protected `API endpoints`. but it not working.

Here, Is my API login method-

```
public function login()
{ 
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $token =  $user->createToken('Personal Access Token')-> accessToken; 

        return response($token,200)->cookie('access_token',$token,10);

    } 
    else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 
}
```

Here, Is my Token middleware -

```
use Cookie;
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    $token=Cookie::get('access_token');
    $response->header('Authorization','Bearer '.$token);

    $response->header('Accept','application/json');
    return $response;

}
```

and the protected routes which i want to access.

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api','api.token'])->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: Did you follow the laravel docs on setting up passport? Also if your route is in the api file are you calling `api/user` from the frontend?

Comment: yes,my url like `example.test/api/user` and follow docs install and config the passport.

Comment: Ok, what is the error you are getting when you make your call?

Comment: it's redirect to the login every time, and don't add the `token` in header but non-protected routes add token in their header.

Comment: Ok so that tells me something is going wrong in your middleware. Nothing is jumping out at me so you will need to put debug statements `dd()` in your middleware to ensure that your values are correct. Sorry I can't be more help.